# Easiest way to export dictionary (or current output text file) to .csv file instead of a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I created a parser and extractor for a log file and wanted to see an example of a quick way to either:

1. Take current output written onto a .txt file and convert it into a new .csv file (possibly with `pandas`), or
2. Use the .csv module to change the write method sequence into a `csv.writer` and then using `csv.DictReader`.

What is most efficient in terms of practicality and resource consumption? My current exported `.txt` file and relevant code is posted below.

Exported data:

```
Request ID : bf710010
Username   : kadaniel
ECID       : 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac
Start Time : 2019-06-12T09:14:54.947
End Time   : 2019-06-12T09:14:55.22

Request ID : bf710020
Username   : kadaniel
ECID       : 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac
Start Time : 2019-06-12T09:14:55.343
End Time   : 2019-06-12T09:14:55.514
```

Code:

```
process_records = {}

with open(log_file_path, "r") as file:

    for line in file:
        m = pattern.match(line)
        if m is not None:        # If there is a match with pattern
            (timestamp, ecid, requestid, username) = m.groups()
            if requestid not in process_records:
                process_records[requestid] = (timestamp, username, ecid, None)
            else:
                process_records[requestid] = process_records[requestid][:3] + (timestamp,)

    for requestid, (start, username, ecid, end) in process_records.items():
        print("Request ID: {}\nUsername: {}\nECID: {}\nStart Time: {}\nEnd Time: {}\n\n".format(
                requestid,
                username,
                ecid,
                start,
                end,
            ))

file.close()

with open(export_file, 'w+') as file:

    file.write("EXPORTED DATA:\n\n")

    if pattern != None:
        for requestid, (start, username, ecid, end) in process_records.items():
                file.write(("Request ID : {}\nUsername   : {}\nECID       : {}\nStart Time : {}\nEnd Time   : {}\n\n".format(
                    requestid,
                    username,
                    ecid,
                    start,
                    end,
                )))

file.close()
```

I currently have the data in a dictionary, `process_records`. Each key (`requestid`) is associated with 4 elements in a tuple. I want the key and each element thereafter to represent its own column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CSV is coma separated. You do not need pandas for this. Only change rule o writing record

```py
with open(export_file, 'w+') as file:

    file.write("Request ID,Username,ECID,Start Time,End Time\n") # header

    if pattern != None:

        for requestid, (start, username, ecid, end) in process_records.items():
                file.write(("{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(
                    requestid,
                    username,
                    ecid,
                    start,
                    end,
                )))  # record

file.close()
```

Comment: What happens when one of those properties has a comma in it?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to do this in my opinion would be to use the builtin [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library.

First, import the library.

```
import csv
```

Then use the following snippet for writing -

```
with open(export_file, 'w+') as file_handler:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fileobj=file_handler, delimiter=',')
    for requestid, (start, username, ecid, end) in process_records.items():
        csv_writer.writerow([requestid, username, ecid, start, end,])
```

Comment: +1 for using an existing csv library, probably tested significantly more than anything we would hack together. You might want to add in how to include a header row.